# why locking read with range condition locks every record when there is only one index column in mysql?

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking

create two tables for comparation:

```
create table t1(id integer primary key);
create table t2(id integer primary key, num integer);
insert into t1 values (0),(3),(6),(9);
insert into t2 values (0, 0), (3, 3), (6, 6), (9, 9);
```

start transaction `tx1` and do a locking read for table `t1`:

```
start transaction;
select * from t1 where id >=3 and id < 8 for update;
```

The locks that `tx1` holds look like this:

[image]

Now rollback `tx1`, start transaction `tx2` and do a locking read for table `t2`:

```
start transaction;
select * from t2 where id >=3 and id < 8 for update;
```

The locks that `tx2` holds look like this:

[image]

The behavior of `tx2` conforms to my understanding of the mysql locking model. Why does `tx1` lock every index record in table `t1`?

================ UPDATE ==================

Now using explain I saw some differences:

[image]

================ UPDATE 2 ==================

As @Bill Karwin 's answer points out, `type: index` means the whole index tree is scanned, see the ref [join-types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html#explain-join-types).

However, if I insert one more row: `insert into t1 values (12)`, the join type changes to `type: range` and it won't lock all index records!

[image]

I guess there are some internal quirks in mysql source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All rows that are examined are locked.

The answer is in the EXPLAIN report. The query that does `type: index` is doing an index-scan, which examines every member of the index. In the case of the PRIMARY index, this effectively examines the whole table.

The query that does `type: range` is examining a subset of the rows.

The optimizer chose to do an index-scan for some reason. I'm not sure exactly why. It could depend on the version of MySQL you are using. You can check with this query: `SELECT VERSION();`

---

I believe this query is treated as an index-scan when it's a covering index. That is the EXPLAIN note that says "Using index." If the columns fetched by the query are the same columns in the index, then it's a covering index.

You get the same optimization strategy (index scan) if you test this query:

```
select id from t2 where id >=3 and id < 8 for update;
```

Because `id` is the column of the primary key index, and it's the only column returned by the query.

Comment: The version is 8.0.29

Comment: See my latest update, it seems that mysql does some trick when dealing with a few rows

Comment: Yes, that's true. If the whole table fits on one page, the optimizer concludes that the cost of reading the whole table is virtually the same as trying to narrow down the search.